# MTOM Request in Progress OpenEdge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am currently trying to send an MTOM post request to a SOAP Service. This is relatively easy to do via SOAPUI5 using some [parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsZwS.png).

This seems to adjusts values within the content-type from this:

Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="..."

to this:

Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"; action="..."; boundary="..."

Im trying to recreate this behaviour in a Progress Application with the System.Net. Client. I have tried to look for a parameter inside the System.Net.HttpWebRequest class that I can change to recreate this behaviour, but I couldn't find a way to get to there. Is it possible to send a MTOM request with the System.Net Client?

UPDATE:
My Code currently looks like this (Some Values were changed):

```
USING System.Net.HttpWebRequest FROM ASSEMBLY.
USING System.Net.WebRequest FROM ASSEMBLY.
USING System.Net.HttpWebResponse FROM ASSEMBLY.
USING System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 FROM ASSEMBLY.
USING System.Text.Encoding FROM ASSEMBLY.

DEFINE VARIABLE cert AS System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE req AS System.Net.HttpWebRequest NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE uri AS System.Uri NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE response AS System.Net.HttpWebResponse NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE payLoad AS "System.Byte[]" NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE payLoadString AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE postReqStream AS System.IO.Stream NO-UNDO.

&scope soaprequest_checkAccountActive " ~
--MIME_Boundary ~~n~
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=UTF-8;type='application/soap+xml';action='checkAccountActive' ~~n~
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit ~~n~
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org> ~~n~
   ~~n~
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> ~~n~
    <soap:Envelope ~~n~
        xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' ~~n~
        xmlns:tran='http://www.osci.eu/ws/2014/10/transport' ~~n~
        xmlns:oas='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' ~~n~
        xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'> ~~n~
        <soap:Header xmlns:wsa='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'> ~~n~
            <tran:Author> ~~n~
                <tran:Identifier type='xoev' name='&2' category='&3'>&1</tran:Identifier> ~~n~
            </tran:Author> ~~n~
            <wsa:Action>http://www.xta.de/XTA/CheckAccountActive</wsa:Action> ~~n~
            <wsa:To>&4</wsa:To> ~~n~
            <wsa:MessageId>&5</wsa:MessageId> ~~n~
            <wsa:ReplyTo> ~~n~
                <wsa:Address></wsa:Address> ~~n~
            </wsa:ReplyTo> ~~n~
        </soap:Header> ~~n~
        <soap:Body/> ~~n~
    </soap:Envelope> ~~n~
    ~~n~
--MIME_Boundary"
                                        
System.Net.ServicePointManager:SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType:Tls12.
cert = NEW X509Certificate2("C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\SomeCert.pfx", "SomePassword").

ASSIGN
uri = NEW System.Uri ("www.mtomurl.com")
req    = CAST (WebRequest:Create (uri), HttpWebRequest).

payLoadString = SUBSTITUTE({&soaprequest_checkAccountActive},
                                        "param1",
                                        "param2",
                                        "param3",
                                        "param4",
                                        "param5").

                                        
payLoad = Encoding:UTF8:GetBytes(payLoadString).





ASSIGN      
            req:Method              = 'POST'.
            req:ContentType         = "multipart/related; type="
                                       + Quoter ("application/xop+xml")
                                       + "; " + "start="
                                       + Quoter ("<rootpart@soapui.org>")
                                       + "; start-info="
                                       + Quoter("application/soap+xml")
                                       + "; action="
                                       + Quoter ("http://www.xta.de/XTA/CheckAccountActive")
                                       + "; boundary="
                                       + QUOTER("--MIME_Boundary").
                           
            req:Headers:Set("MIME-Version", "1.0").
            req:KeepAlive           = TRUE.
            req:UserAgent           = "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)".


postReqStream = req:GetRequestStream().
postReqStream:write(payLoad, 0, payLoad:Length).
postReqStream:Close().

req:ClientCertificates:Add(cert).
    
response = CAST (req:GetResponse (), HttpWebResponse).

MESSAGE response:StatusCode
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: What OpenEdge version and platform are you using?

Comment: @MikeFechner Progress 12.2 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by looking at the .NET documentation and code samples. It's often a very simple translation from C# to ABL.

Comment: Thats what i did. I tried adding the Headers like in [this](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/soap_mtom_post.asp) example. I keep getting a HTTP Error 400.

Comment: Post your code so far!